# Can't enter javascript using CKEditor dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Been trying to enter some javascript using a CKEditor dialog, tried `editor.document.createFromHtml('<script> some javascript </script>');`
which only created a set of empty script tags. Did not really change anything and now I get the error:

> createFromHtml is not a function

and cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
onOk : function()
{
    //var eHtml = this.getContentElement('tab1','selectedGraph').getElement();
    var graphscript = editor.document.createFromHtml( ' <script type="text/javascript"> <script>' );    
    //var graph = editor.document.createElement( 'div' );
    //graph.setAttribute('id', 'graph'); //dialog.getValueOf( 'tab1', 'abbr' ) );
    //editor.insertElement( graph );



    //graphscript.setValue('test'); //dialog.getValueOf( 'tab1', 'abbr' ) );
    //editor.insertElement( graphscript );      

}
```

Comment: check out: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Trouble-getting-CKEditor-to-load-in-a-jqueryui-Dialog-where-the-dialog-used-load-url

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out but wasn't sure how to use that thread, probably should have mentioned I'm using a custom plugin.

Comment: go here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97149/php-mysql-html-css-and-js i will try to help you

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using this:

`CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml('somejavascipt', editor.document );`

Comment: but I havn't figured out yet how to get it to run the script

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Trouble-getting-CKEditor-to-load-in-a-jqueryui-Dialog-where-the-dialog-used-load-url

http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Second-Time-jQuery-Doesnt-Work

they had the same problem then figured it out so this should help you